# Show cut-off line in mini buffer?

Tags: mode-line, echo-area, wrapping, ecb

When using ECB, the lines for function names are often long and get cut-off in the sidebar:

[image]

Is there a way to show the full line that the cursor is at in the mini buffer when it is cut off due to its window not being wide enough?

Comment: Show it in the *mode-line*, not the echo area (same screen space as the minibuffer, which is for *input*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case of ECB, I solved this by realizing that on mouse hover over the method in ECB's methods buffer, a tooltip is shown with the full function definition. I then put this into my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
;; show tooltips in echo area
(tooltip-mode -1)
(setq tooltip-use-echo-area t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x t") 'display-local-help) ;; show tooltip
```

Now, putting the point over a cut-off function in ECB's methods area and pressing `C-x t` shows the full function in the echo area, as I wanted:

[image]